# client/server and browser/server

Tags: php, client-server

How to compare client/server and browser/server architecture? Or what are their respective advantages and disadvantages?

Consider PHP programming, is there any difference when using it in client/server and browser/server programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be muxing your terminology.  When you're using a browser, IT is the "client" in that case.  When you're using PHP via command line, YOU are the client (or your operating system, depending on you want to look at it).

There isn't really a comparison between "client/server" architecture and "browser/server" architecture - they are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

Browser acts as a client. So, in web world, browser/server is in-fact client/server thing.